# Child Content Type (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I need to create two content types (Call List and Call Announcements), in Call Announcements there are 5 fields, in Call List there are 12 fields but 5 of them are mutual with Call Announcements, I do not want to create 2 different content types (Call List, Call Announcements) because when the user create a node, he should be able to choose where the node is shown (in Call List, in Call Announcements, Both).
(Call List and Call Announcements should be in the same database table)

How can I do these?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAgXM.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single content type containing all the fields.

After that add a field with checkboxes with the options like, "show on call list" and "show on call announcements), This extra field can be used to decide how the create/edit/view behaves.

**When Creating/Updating content.**

Now you may go ahead and install [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields), if you want to conditionally show some field based on the values of checkboxes selected.

**When viewing content**

Use [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display the list. Here you can decide what is shown in the list by filtering the list by the checkbox values. As a bonus extra views would help you decide what fields need to be shown to the user.